# ArrayIndexOutofBounds error with no array in command line

Tags: java, command-prompt

So this is for an assignment that in essence the program depending on the args[1], will either display to the command prompt all that is in a desired text file and write whatever is in that file along with a calculated GPA to a new file specified in args[2]. The second option will display only the GPA but write all to a specified file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class gpahw {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        double sum = 0;
        double numclasses = 0;

        if (args.length < 1 || args.length > 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java gpahw coursestakenn.txt, -o || -fo, new file.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        if (args[1].equals("-o")) {
            // display only gpa but write classes and gpa to file
            File outputfile = new File(args[2]);
            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(outputfile);
            File inputfile = new File(args[0]);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(inputfile);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                char letter = line.charAt(line.length() - 1);
                if (letter == 'A') {
                    sum += 4;
                } else if (letter == 'B') {
                    sum += 3;
                } else if (letter == 'C') {
                    sum += 2;
                } else if (letter == 'D') {
                    sum += 1;
                }
                //System.out.println(line);
                numclasses++;
                write.println(line);
                //write.println("GPA: " + sum / numclasses);

            }
                write.println("GPA: " + sum / numclasses);
            System.out.println("GPA: " + sum / numclasses);
            input.close();
            write.close();
        } else if (args[1].equals("-fo")) {
            // display all and write all to file
            File outputfile = new File(args[2]);
            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(outputfile);
            File inputfile = new File(args[0]);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(inputfile);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                char letter = line.charAt(line.length() - 1);
                if (letter == 'A') {
                    sum += 4;
                } else if (letter == 'B') {
                    sum += 3;
                } else if (letter == 'C') {
                    sum += 2;
                } else if (letter == 'D') {
                    sum += 1;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
                numclasses++;
                write.println(line);

            }
                write.println("GPA: " + sum / numclasses);
            System.out.println("GPA: " + sum / numclasses);
            input.close();
            write.close();

        } 
        if (args.length == 1) {
            //supposed to just display what is in file and display calculate GPA
            File inputfile = new File(args[0]);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(inputfile);
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                char letter = line.charAt(line.length() - 1);
                if (letter == 'A') {
                    sum += 4;
                } else if (letter == 'B') {
                    sum += 3;
                } else if (letter == 'C') {
                    sum += 2;
                } else if (letter == 'D') {
                    sum += 1;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
                numclasses++;

            }
            System.out.println("GPA: " + sum / numclasses);
            input.close();
        }

}
```

The error i get in the command prompt is  an array index out of bound when i try to call "java gpahw courses.txt", this is just supposed to display whatever is in the text file specified and display the calculated GPA, but not write anything to a new file. The program works perfectly fine if i call "java gpahw courses.txt -o coursestaken.txt" or the same except the other option. Sorry if my code is very messy and redundant.

Comment: Recompile. Your `if` check before accessing the `args[1]` element isn't present in your byte code.

Comment: Basically you're allowing for a range of `1` to `3`, but aren't checking to see if there actually in values within that range (you know that there might be between `1` and `3` items, but not how many there actually are)

Comment: @MadProgrammer ahh okay, correct me if im wrong but you're saying i should add and "if" to check the length of arguments and then from there execute the other options. For example, if(args.length == 3) { arguments etc...}

Comment: Based on my understand of your command line requirements, I would imagine that the exception is that the `args` count must be `3`, so `args.length == 3` would be a more accurate check

Comment: @MadProgrammer Partially correct, the number of command line arguments can be either 1 or 3 since 2 arguments would not write to a specified file.

Comment: I might consider doing something more like: `if length == 1 {...} else if length == 3 {...} else { // wrong }`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay then, once again correct me if i'm wrong but i should first check if there is only 1 command line argument, if true do what it's supposed to, if wrong check if there's 3 arguments, then do what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @F.ochoa15 Pretty much. You've determine that the array either contains `1` or `3` elements, at that point it's much safer to access up to that number of elements in the array

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alrighty then, i'll fix my code around and then retest it. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: instead of nesting `if`s, just use a switch, or direct math like this `sum += 4 -
 (letter - 'A')`

Comment: @madprogrammer did what you said and it works how it's supposed to!